# How to change the line spacing when printing a Gmail?

Tags: gmail, printing

When I see an email on my monitor in Gmail the line spacing is just fine. Single line spacing, no screen real estate is wasted. However, when I print that same email all of a sudden it has double line spacing. Is there any way to avoid this? I have noticed this on different computers and printers.